# How to generate .exe files on the runtime in C#

Tags: c#, exe

i want a program in which user when clicks on button, my program generates an exe file after writing all the data on a file.

User can tick or untick number of checboxes and then when user clicks on button, it writes all the required data according to checkboxes state in exe file.

Now according to me the only way to do that is, first generate the exe file open it with notepad and copy the data in it, now code a program which create an exe file with that data.

Is there any other way to generate exe files at runtime?

Comment: Write data in exe? first generate the exe file open it with notepad...? What are you thinking.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  I don't think it's quite clear what you're asking.  A file is just a file regardless of the extension.  Are you trying to create an actual windows executable by manually specifying the byte contents of the file?  There's a bunch of apps out there that already do that, but they're normally just called "compilers".  Could you be a little more specific what you want.

Comment: @Dan have you ever used a RAT or a keylogger. When you click on build server an exe file is generated which has its own functionality. What i want is my program generates another program which have its own functionality based on the options user chose.

Comment: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/304655

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a potentially related project [here](http://garry.tv/2012/02/12/bundler/).
[Google code page and  Source](http://code.google.com/p/bundler/). It is written in C++.

From the project's page.

> It simply adds the other files, zipped up, on to the back of a launcher exe. Then when the program runs it unzips those files into a temporary directory and runs your program.

You could do something similar, creating your program to check for the end of itself and then either adding data or reading the data.

If that isn't what you mean then perhaps you could look into [Reflection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7ykdhsy.aspx) or the .net [CodeDom](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/650ax5cx.aspx).

Comment: i think thats what i was searching for, CodeDom. Ill read about CodeDom and i hope it works.